# 'LOG' backup using Ola Hallengren doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, backup

For some reason LOG backup doesn't bring the .trn file in specified location.

It does work with FULL, DIFF parameters but NOT with LOG.

Is it a bug or I am missing something?

Same folder structure, same account executing code, same permissions.
Database in FULL recovery mode.
No error generated. It just does not deliver file.

[image]

```
EXEC master.dbo.DatabaseBackup 
    @BackupType = 'LOG', -- changing this to 'FULL' or 'DIFF' works fine
    @Databases = 'AdventureWorks2017',
    @Directory = '\\path\to\drive\',  
    @Verify = 'Y',
    @Compress = 'Y',
    @CheckSum = 'Y',
    @CleanupTime = 24,
    @LogToTable = 'Y',
    @FileName = '{ServerName}${InstanceName}_{DatabaseName}_{Year}{Month}{Day}{Hour}{Minute}.{FileExtension}'
```

Comment: Is your `AdventureWorks2017` set for the `FULL` recovery model?

Comment: Yes. It is in `FULL` recovery model.

Comment: I have log shipping configured on AdventureWorks2017 as well, but I don't think this could effect it.

Comment: You may want to look at what you're passing in for `@ExcludeLogShippedFromLogBackup`

Comment: When you run the above command in SSMS, what is the output of the procedure?

Comment: @ErikDarling Thank you! I thought I am going nuts. I updated stored procedure with the last version and was able to use parameter ExcludeLogShippedFromLogBackup = 'N'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. **@ExcludeLogShippedFromLogBackup** parameter value is 'N'. Database recovery model is set to Simple.

My Full Backup and DIFF backup works perfectly. The backup is taken to the Azure Blob container.

Below is the command inside the Step (SQL job)

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES,-TBPSmsSystemArchive%',
@Url='https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/sql-db-backup',
@BackupType = 'LOG',
@Verify = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = NULL,
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y',
@BlockSize=65536,
@MaxTransferSize=4194304,
@ExcludeLogShippedFromLogBackup = 'N'
```

Comment: I think database would need to be in FULL recovery mode in order to be able to take LOG backups.

Comment: @Serdia I tried with Recovery model to FULL and ran the SQL job for log backup. Still no luck. Any things else that I will need to check?

Comment: @Serdia, I tried with @OverrideBackupPreference='Y' also and it still was not working. The next day when I checked the LOG backups started to work. Only change was that during midnight the DIFF backup happened and I am left to assume that that could a a possible reason for LOG backups to work. Thanks.